# Raid5 reconstruction is extremely slow

Tags: ubuntu, raid, raid-5

Three days ago added another drive to my RAID5 array with 3 drives, each drive is 4TB.
Since then than only `42% has been completed`

```
MegaCli64 -LDRecon ShowProg L0 -a0                                     
Reconstruction on VD #0 (target id #0) Completed 42% in 502 Minutes.
```

I've tried increasing reconstruction rate, but I didn't notice any increase in speed

```
MegaCli64 -AdpAllInfo -aALL | grep -i rate
Rebuild Rate                     : 90%
PR Rate                          : 30%
BGI Rate                         : 30%
Check Consistency Rate           : 30%
Reconstruction Rate              : 90%
Ecc Bucket Leak Rate             : 1440 Minutes
Rebuild Rate                    : Yes
CC Rate                         : Yes
BGI Rate                        : Yes
Reconstruct Rate                : Yes
Patrol Read Rate                : Yes
Background Rate                  : 30 
BIOS Enumerate VDs               : Yes
```

Is this a normal behavior? because I can only guess how long it would take to reconstruct all my 36 drives on this server.

card module:  `MegaRAID SAS 9271-4i Sgl`

- not sure what's wrong with the time, `502 Minutes` is not the correct info and it's changing randomly every few minutes.

Comment: The information you posted says that it took 502 minutes (a little over 8 hours) to complete 42%, but your question says that you added the drive three days ago. Which is it?

Comment: I think it's a bug, the time changes every few minutes. at the moment it's ` Completed 42% in 342 Minutes.`

Comment: Just as background information: Yes, expanding or reconstructing a previously failed drive part of a RAID 5 array can take a long time. Usually this is not a problem since you can make sure your backups work, wipe and recreate the array. Live expansion on RAID 5 and drives this size?  * *Shudder* *.   Also see U.R.E.

Comment: "RAID5 reconstruction is extremely slow" Yes, yes it is.

Comment: is the OS booted during RAID rebuild?  That will slow it down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, RAID 5 rebuilds are slow, especially when very large disks are involved. This completely normal behavior is a huge part of the reason why RAID 5 is generally considered to be obsolete. Don't use it. Use RAID 1+0 or RAID 6, depending on your requirements.

Comment: so reconstructing RAID6 is much faster? I need it for media storage.

Comment: No it's not any faster, but if you have a 2nd failure during the reconstruction (which is not a uncommon occurrence) you don't loose all your data.